# What aspects of Plan 9 have made their way into Unix?

Tags: unix, history, plan9

[Plan 9](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/) was developed by Bell Labs as a successor to Unix. Although for various reasons it never quite materialized as such, a fair amount of development still went into Plan 9.

My question is, what - if anything - from Plan 9 has made its way into modern Unix?

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/plan9.html

Comment: from the paper: *"the most dangerous enemy of a better solution is an existing codebase that is just good enough."*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `clone`(2) system call in linux is [said to](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=863939) have been modeled after Plan 9's `rfork()`. (I personally don't see how the timing works out.)

[This paper](http://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2006/ols2006v1-pages-101-112.pdf) claims that Plan 9 inspired the "mount/filesystem namespace".

The [`/proc` filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) appears to have come to Plan 9 from 8th Edition Unix, rather than the other way around.

Comment: It seems that more and more pieces keep coming over but not enough to port native plan9 applications with 100% original functionality.

Answer (score 20):

The obvious one is probably UTF-8. But that's probably *too* obvious.

Al Viro's grand re-architecturing of the Linux VFS is heavily inspired by Plan9. Especially the shift from "Everything Is A File" to "… And Every File Is A Mount Point".

Comment: Could you briefly explain (or point me to a resource which explains) what is meant by "...and every file is a mount point"?

Comment: @Mr. Shickadance: Traditionally, you can only mount filesystems and you can only mount them on directories. On Linux, you can also mount directories on directories and files on files. So, in a sense, every directory and every file is a filesystem and every file (and not just every directory) is a mountpoint. Example: `cd /tmp; echo a > a; echo b > b; sudo mount --bind a b; cat b # => a`

Answer (score 10):

The /proc filesystem in Linux is a Plan 9 idea.

Comment: See the correct answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8340/128489

Answer (score 8):

Union file systems, such as [unionfs](http://tcos.org/project-unionfs.html) and [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/), were inspired by Plan9 [union directory mounts](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/magic/man2html?man=mount&sect=1).

For example, they are used on live CDs to merge `/usr/bin` from the CD with a writable file system, so that you can make changes to `/usr/bin`, even tho the CD is read-only.

[Union file systems: Implementations, Part I on lwn.net](http://lwn.net/Articles/325369/)

For example, if I understand the docs correctly, on Plan9, you could do:

```
bind -b /usr/bin /bin
bind -b /usr/local/bin /bin
bind -b /home/username/bin /bin
```

And all the files in all three directories would appear in `/bin` (in case of duplicate names, the one in the last-specified directory wins, due to the `-b` option).

I'm not sure if this is what Bruce means by "mount/filesystem namespace", or is something different.

---

You could probably also say that [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) was inspired by Plan9's [ftpfs](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/magic/man2html/4/ftpfs).

Answer (score 4):

In Plan 9, every "filesystem" is implemented by a userspace daemon. (Think FUSE.) These daemons all talk 9P (specifically 9P2000, the second revision of the protocol). 9P is essentially what holds the different parts of the system together.

The [v9fs](http://v9fs.sourceforge.net) project implements a Linux kernel driver for the 9P protocol. According to the [Plan 9 wiki page on it](http://www.plan9.bell-labs.com/wiki/plan9/v9fs/index.html), it is in the mainline kernel as of kernel 2.6.14.